# Rails 3 - correct test for PUT method via rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, model, rspec, rspec-rails

I have model **TeacherLeader** which keeps foreign keys for other tables. I can update this table and i try to write tests for my controller (via rspec).

My model:

```
#  id         :integer         not null, primary key
#  user_id    :integer
#  teacher_id :integer
#

class TeacherLeader < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :teacher

  validates :teacher_id, 
              :uniqueness => { :message => "already a class-head" }
end
```

My controller

```
class TeacherLeadersController < ApplicationController
 def edit
    @teacher_leader = TeacherLeader.find( params[:id] )    
    ...
  end

  def update
    @teacher_leader = TeacherLeader.find( params[:id] )
    ...

    if ( @teacher_leader.update_attributes( params[:teacher_leader] ) )                   
      redirect_to teachers_path
      ...
    else
      redirect_to edit_teacher_leader_path
      ...
      end      
    end
  end
end
```

So, i have problems with writing tests for PUT. Here is example of my code for PUT method:

```
describe TeacherLeadersController do
  render_views

  before(:each) do    
    @teacher = Factory( :teacher )
    @teacher.user.user_role = "teacher"
    @teacher.save!

    @user = Factory( :user, :user_login => Factory.next(:user_login) )
    @user.user_role = "class_head"
    @user.save!

    @sh = Factory( :user, :user_login => Factory.next(:user_login)  )
    @sh.user_role = "school_head"
    @sh.save!
  end

  describe "PUT 'update" do
    before(:each) do
      @teacher_leader = @user.create_teacher_leader( @attr_teacher_leader )
    end

    describe "for signed-in school-heads" do
      before(:each) do
        test_sign_in( @sh )
      end

      it "should update teacher leader with correct params" do
        put :update, :id => @teacher_leader, :teacher_id => @teacher.id
        @teacher_leader.reload
        @teacher_leader.teacher_id.should  == @teacher.id
      end
    end
  end
end
```

When i try to run my specs i get that:

```
1) TeacherLeadersController PUT 'update for signed-in school-heads should update teacher leader with correct params
     Failure/Error: put :update, :id => @teacher_leader, :teacher_id => @teacher.id
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
     # ./app/controllers/teacher_leaders_controller.rb:57:in `update'
     # ./spec/controllers/teacher_leaders_controller_spec.rb:150:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

But my application works! What do i do in tests wrong?

Comment: May be `put :update, :id => @teacher_leader.id, ...`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your controller is expecting a `params[:teacher_leader]` hash, but your test doesn't supply it. Try this:

```
it "should update teacher leader with correct params" do
  put :update, :id => @teacher_leader, :teacher_leader => { :teacher_id => @teacher.id }
  # ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure if your specs are wrapped with `describe TeacherLeadersController` block. For example:

```
describe TeacherLeadersController do
  describe "PUT 'update" do
    #...

    describe "for signed-in school-heads" do
      it "should update teacher leader with correct params" do
        put :update, :id => @teacher_leader, :teacher_id => @teacher.id
      end
    end
  end
end
```

..then you should be able to use `put` method correctly.

Also you forgot to pass `:teacher_leader` attributes to the controller under the test. Try `put :update, :id => something, :teacher_leader => { some_attributes_here }`

Anyway I strongly recommend you to mock all database queries (active record calls) in the controller specs. For testing whether params are persisted you should use requests specs (or other method for doing integration / acceptance tests). See for example: http://blog.bandzarewicz.com/slides/krug-the-perfect-rspec/#27